# Regex matching playlist id in spotify link

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract the playlist id from a spotify link. The link could come in two forms:

`https://open.spotify.com/playlist/1GXN1gZMuTlW5LjpTNJF2q`

`https://open.spotify.com/playlist/1GXN1gZMuTlW5LjpTNJF2q?si=d3fa4293e26049f8`

expected result => 1GXN1gZMuTlW5LjpTNJF2q

I've tried `(?<=\/playlist\/)(.*)(?=\?|$)` to match between /playlist/ and the end or a question mark, but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) interface to get the path.

```
new URL(uri).pathname.split('/').pop()
```

```js
const uri = 'https://open.spotify.com/playlist/1GXN1gZMuTlW5LjpTNJF2q?si=d3fa4293e26049f8';
console.log(new URL(uri).pathname.split('/').pop());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern should use a non greedy quantifier `(?<=\/playlist\/).*?(?=\?|$)` but in this case you don't need any lookarounds at all. You can use a capture group instead with a negated character class matching any character except for `?`

If you want to match spotify links only, you can make the pattern more specific

```
\bhttps?:\/\/[^/]*\bspotify\.com\/playlist\/([^\s?]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QLMTDn/1)

Or only for `open.spotify`

```
\bhttps?:\/\/open.spotify\.com\/playlist\/([^\s?]+)
```

```js
const regex = /\bhttps?:\/\/[^/]*\bspotify\.com\/playlist\/([^\s?]+)/;
[
  "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/1GXN1gZMuTlW5LjpTNJF2q",
  "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/1GXN1gZMuTlW5LjpTNJF2q?si=d3fa4293e26049f8"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[1])
  }
});
```